# No puedo extraer los datos del objeto "text" de un json, necesito hacerlo en java

Tags: java, json, objeto

Este es el json que obtengo de respuesta de la Vision API de Google, necesito extraer el Objeto "text" del array "responses", seria de gran ayuda que pueda extraer esa data.

```html
{
"responses":[  
      { 
     "textAnnotations":[],
     "fullTextAnnotation":{
            "pages":[],
             "text":"texto a obtener"
                          }
      }
           ]
}
```

Comment: Hola .Sebastin Leyva Chumpitaz, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Encontre la solucion en este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058240/extracting-data-from-json-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente intenta recorrer el json con el nombre de la variable

```js
json={
"responses":[  
      { 
     "textAnnotations":[],
     "fullTextAnnotation":{
            "pages":[],
             "text":"texto a obtener"
                          }
      }
           ]
};
console.log(json.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text)
```

**Actualización**

Para JAVA puedes utilizar la libreria [java-json.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm)

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{\"responses\":[  \n" +
                        "      { \n" +
                        "     \"textAnnotations\":[],\n" +
                        "     \"fullTextAnnotation\":{\n" +
                        "            \"pages\":[],\n" +
                        "             \"text\":\"texto a obtener\"\n" +
                        "                          }\n" +
                        "      }\n" +
                        "           ]\n" +
                        "}"); 
        System.out.println(json.getJSONArray("responses").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("fullTextAnnotation").get("text").toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero mi inquietud esta desarrollarlo en java.

Comment: Bueno ya edite la respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias  me funciono perfectamente.